# how to sort array by inner array size

Tags: php

how to sort array by inner array size?

i want to sort my array by size of array inside. each array that has more items most put at the end and each array has less items most got to top.

**note: I want sum of size of all items and sub items.**

this is my array:

```
$myArray = array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'item1' => 80,
    'item2' => 81,
    'item3' => 83,
    'item4' => 84,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'item3' => array (
       'item1' => 85,
       'item2' => 85,
       'item3' => 85,
       'item4' => 85,
       'item5' => 85,
    ),
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'item1' => 25,
    'item2' => 22,
    'item3' => 11,
  ),
)
```

i want this output:

```
array (
  0 => 
  array (
    'item1' => 25,
    'item2' => 22,
    'item3' => 11,
  ),
  1 => 
  array (
    'item1' => 80,
    'item2' => 81,
    'item3' => 83,
    'item4' => 84,
  ),
  2 => 
  array (
    'item3' => array (
       'item1' => 85,
       'item2' => 85,
       'item3' => 85,
       'item4' => 85,
       'item5' => 85,
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: This won't work anyway. You can't have the same key multiple times....

Comment: i was just putting example and forgot to change keys just duplicating them that's reason of  unique key repeats. i updated the question@Steven

Comment: i have no idea. @RiggsFolly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Array Keys

You can't have the same `unique` key repeated in an array

```
$arr = ["item1" => 1, "item1" => 2];
// Is equivalent to: 
//    $arr = ["item1" => 2];
```

### Your question

**Key knowledge:**

- `count($array, $recurse = FALSE)`
- `usort($array, $function)`
- `<=>` *spaceship* operator

Using `usort` we can use a defined a function to sort the array. The function will be passed two variables to compare at a time and must return `<0 | 0 | >0` depending whether `a` is less than, equal to, or greater than `b`.

To count the `keys` in the array we can use the recursive move of `count` by setting the second parameter to `TRUE`.

We can then use `count` inside of our function to count `a` and `b` and compare the result.

```
$array = [
    [1,2,3,4],
    [1,2,[1,2,3,4,5]],
    [1,2,3]
];

function compare_size($a, $b){
    return (count($a, TRUE)<=>count($b, TRUE));
}
usort($array, "compare_size");

echo json_encode($array);


/*
  Output:
    [
      [1,2,3],
      [1,2,3,4],
      [1,2,[1,2,3,4,5]]
    ]
*/


)
```

Comment: i was just putting example and forgot to change keys just duplicating them that's reason of  unique key repeats. and the answer is correct thanks